# Circle CI Analysis

Tags: circleci

I am curious if it is possible to automatically measure whether a test suite is flaky from the Circle CI interface. I would measure flaky as - fail and pass with a re-trigger. Is this possible to easily do?

Comment: Update on 2022: as of now it is indeed possible and very easy to do. Here's the article https://circleci.com/blog/introducing-test-insights-with-flaky-test-detection/

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment, as far as I'm aware. I've done an extensive research on build insights in general, which included flaky tests analysis and monitoring, and finally decided to build my own tool. The good news is that last I checked, they seem to be focusing on creating better insights tools [in addition to what they currently have](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/insights/). They'll tell you all about it if you reach out to them.

In the interim, you have a few options:

1. Ask them how far away are they from supporting for your idea of what a flaky is (I'm hoping this point gets outdated shortly as they work on it)
2. Consume their data through their decent enough API, and build your own tool in the interim and crunch the numbers yourself (this is what I ended up doing and it isn't too bad)

For example: generally speaking, a flaky for my team is a test that failed more than a few times over a large timespan. Their API gives you whether a build failed or not, which test failed, when and how. This gave me enough to work with and figure out whether I consider that spec failure as flaky or not. I'd assume yours is sort of similar, with maybe the only difference being whether it was re-triggered (unsure if they provide that info specifically, but you could refer to the workflow, commit and build ID to figure that out; e.g. if the build ID of a new run is the same).

With that beind said, the "how easy is it?" part of your question is something I can't really say for certain. It was a relatively easy learning curve to go through their APIs, get familiar with it, run a couple of requests, look at the data, massage it, store in the DB, then build a web interface around it. But I'm not sure how much familiarity and experience the people building the tool on your end have.